# Maven archetype:generate excessive number of choice

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

According to maven [site](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html), and some tutorials on the web, mvn archetype:generate would give a choice of about 36, and selection 15 is the quick start. It was working this way until I setup [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) . Now I get a choice of 358 with default as 97 (which I am could not read the description from my dos prompt). Is both choices are same? Why now I get these many choices. How to correct it if I have to change my repository setttings. My maven version is

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 15:16:01-0400)
Java version: 1.6.0_16
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows vista" version: "6.0" arch: "amd64" Family: "windows"
```

Thanks.

```
339: remote -> parallelj-archetype (ParallelJ is a Java framework for parallel computing. It provides flow modeling and execution.)
340: remote -> parancoe-pluginarchetype (-)
341: remote -> parancoe-webarchetype (-)
342: remote -> liftweb-archetype-blank (Archetype - blank project for liwftweb)
343: remote -> liftweb-archetype-hellolift (Archetype - hellolift sample liwftweb application)
344: remote -> scala-archetype-simple (The maven-scala-plugin is used for compiling/testing/running/documenting scala code in maven.)
345: remote -> slf4j-archetype (The slf4j Archetype)
346: remote -> flexmojos-archetypes-application (-)
347: remote -> flexmojos-archetypes-library (-)
348: remote -> flexmojos-archetypes-modular-webapp (-)
349: remote -> nexus-plugin-archetype (-)
350: remote -> spring-osgi-bundle-archetype (Spring OSGi Maven2 Archetype)
351: remote -> spring-ws-archetype (Spring Web Services Maven2 Archetype.)
352: remote -> trails-archetype (-)
353: remote -> trails-secure-archetype (-)
354: remote -> tynamo-archetype (-)
355: remote -> wicket-scala-archetype (Basic setup for a project that combines Scala and Wicket,
                depending on the Wicket-Scala project. Includes an example Specs
                test.)
356: remote -> wikbook.archetype (-)
357: remote -> circumflex-archetype (-)
358: remote -> javg-minimal-archetype (-)
Choose a number: 97:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for the same solution and I seem to find a usable one, though it may not suit everyone.

The idea is to create a local archetype catalog and specify all archetypes you may need there.
This way you'll get only choices you're interested.

Of course you may find you'll need to add new archetype there, then you'll need either to fallback to normal use of remote repository or add it by hand.

The recipe:

1. Create the initial local catalog with

   `mvn archetype:crawl -Dcatalog=~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml`
2. Pass catalog list from only you're local catalog to archetype:generate

   `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local`

You will see something like this:

```
grim@blackbox:~/projects$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local

[ ...bullshit... ]

Choose archetype:
1: local -> maven-archetype-quickstart (quickstart)
2: local -> maven-archetype-archetype (archetype)
3: local -> maven-archetype-webapp (webapp)
Choose a number: 1:
```

You can make the option permanent by specifying it in your settings.xml:

```
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
           <archetypeCatalog>local</archetypeCatalog>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Now when you want to fallback to usual Maven catalog list, run it as

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=remote,local
```

and you will have all archetypes available.

Answer (score 2):

I see maven 3 is available and installed without nexus.. that gave same number of choices as below. So, somehow I was getting maven 3 archetype earlier.. seems like 97 is a good choice..

```
PS C:\>  mvn archetype:generate
Choose archetype:
1: remote -> docbkx-quickstart-archetype (-)
2: remote -> multi (-)
3: remote -> simple (-)
4: remote -> apparat-archetype-asm (-)
5: remote -> apparat-archetype-tdsi (-)
6: remote -> gquery-archetype (-)
7: remote -> gquery-plugin-archetype (-)
8: remote -> jdbc-proc-archetype (Creates simple project with jdbc-proc support)
9: remote -> liferay-layouttpl-archetype (Provides an archetype to create Liferay layout templates.)
10: remote -> liferay-portlet-archetype (Provides an archetype to create Liferay portlets.)
11: remote -> liferay-theme-archetype (Provides an archetype to create Liferay themes.)
12: remote -> rdfbean-tapestry-quickstart (Archetype for creating a basic RDFBean Tapestry 5 application.)
13: remote -> j2me-simple (Maven 2 Archetype for midlet application using j2me-maven-plugin)
14: remote -> vaadin-archetype-clean (This archetype generates a simple Vaadin application as a Maven project.
      No custom widgetset is included.)
15: remote -> vaadin-archetype-sample (This archetype generates a Vaadin application as a Maven project.
      The application contains a custom GWT widgetset that is compiled
      by the GWT compiler and integrated into the project as part of the
      build process. The application is based on the Vaadin Color Picker
      Demo application available at http://vaadin.com.)
16: remote -> vaadin-archetype-widget (This archetype generates a Vaadin widget project for Vaadin 6.2+ and a test appli
cation.)
17: remote -> android-quickstart (Creates a skeleton for an Android application)
18: remote -> android-with-test (Creates a skeleton for an Android application and instrumentation tests)
19: remote -> jbosscc-seam-archetype (Maven Archetype to generate a Seam Application)
20: remote -> rails-maven-archetype (archetype to mavenize an existing rails 2.3.x or rails3 application)
21: remote -> maven-archetype-flex (An archetype which contains a sample Maven Flex project using the israfil maven plug
in)
22: remote -> javate-zk-archetype (Archetype for a JavATE project that uses Hibernate and ZK.)
23: remote -> web-quickstart (Context Web Application Framework - Quickstart)
24: remote -> data-app (To make creating a new Databinder application easier, this archetype includes all required sourc
es and resources.)
25: remote -> data-app (To make creating a new Databinder application easier, this archetype includes all required sourc
es and resources.)
26: remote -> gae-archetype-gwt (Archetype for creating maven-gae projects that uses GWT for the view)
27: remote -> gae-archetype-jsf (Archetype for creating maven-gae projects that works under Java Server Faces)
28: remote -> gae-archetype-jsp (Archetype for creating maven-gae projects that uses jsp for the view)
29: remote -> gae-archetype-objectify-jsp (Archetype for creating maven-gae projects that uses jsp for the view and Obje
ctify for the ORM.)
30: remote -> gae-archetype-wicket (Archetype for creating maven-gae projects based on apache wicket framework)
31: remote -> lift-archetype-basic (Basic project archetype for Lift Web Framework (with database, logging, user managem
ent).)
32: remote -> lift-archetype-basic_2.7.7 (Basic project archetype for Lift Web Framework (with database, logging, user m
anagement).)
33: remote -> lift-archetype-basic_2.8.0 (Basic project archetype for Lift Web Framework (with database, logging, user m
anagement).)
34: remote -> lift-archetype-basic_2.8.1 (Basic project archetype for Lift Web Framework (with database, logging, user m
anagement).)
35: remote -> lift-archetype-blank (Blank project archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
36: remote -> lift-archetype-blank_2.7.7 (Blank project archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
37: remote -> lift-archetype-blank_2.8.0 (Blank project archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
38: remote -> lift-archetype-blank_2.8.1 (Blank project archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
39: remote -> lift-archetype-hellolift (Archetype - hellolift, a sample Lift application)
40: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-basic (Basic JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
41: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-basic_2.7.7 (Basic JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
42: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-basic_2.8.0 (Basic JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
43: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-basic_2.8.1 (Basic JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
44: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-blank (Blank JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
45: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-blank-single (Blank JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework (single project).)
46: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-blank-single_2.7.7 (Blank JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework (single project).)
47: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-blank-single_2.8.0 (Blank JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework (single project).)
48: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-blank-single_2.8.1 (Blank JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework (single project).)
49: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-blank_2.7.7 (Blank JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
50: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-blank_2.8.0 (Blank JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
51: remote -> lift-archetype-jpa-blank_2.8.1 (Blank JPA archetype for Lift Web Framework.)
52: remote -> lift-archetype-sbt (Basic project archetype for Lift Web Framework (with database, logging, user managemen
t) using the sbt build system)
53: remote -> lift-archetype-sbt_2.7.7 (Basic project archetype for Lift Web Framework (with database, logging, user man
agement) using the sbt build system)
54: remote -> lift-archetype-sbt_2.8.0 (Basic project archetype for Lift Web Framework (with database, logging, user man
agement) using the sbt build system)
55: remote -> lift-archetype-sbt_2.8.1 (Basic project archetype for Lift Web Framework (with database, logging, user man
agement) using the sbt build system)
56: remote -> jlue-archetype-basic (Archetype - basic project for Jlue)
57: remote -> jlue-archetype-blank (Archetype - blank project for Jlue)
58: remote -> maven-archetype-har (-)
59: remote -> maven-archetype-sar (-)
60: remote -> maven-archetype-gwt (An archetype which contains a sample Maven GWT project.)
61: remote -> portletunit-portlet-archetype (An archetype that creates a simple porltet with unit tests.)
62: remote -> antlr3-maven-archetype (-)
63: remote -> camel-component (-)
64: remote -> camel-router (-)
65: remote -> camel-archetype-activemq (Creates a new Camel project that configures and interacts with ActiveMQ.)
66: remote -> camel-archetype-component (Creates a new Camel component.)
67: remote -> camel-archetype-java (Creates a new Camel project using Java DSL.)
68: remote -> camel-archetype-scala (Creates a new Camel project using Scala DSL.)
69: remote -> camel-archetype-spring (Creates a new Camel project with added Spring DSL support.)
70: remote -> camel-archetype-war (Creates a new Camel project that deploys the Camel Web Console, REST API, and your ro
utes as a WAR)
71: remote -> cocoon-22-archetype-block (-)
72: remote -> cocoon-22-archetype-block-plain (-)
73: remote -> cocoon-22-archetype-webapp (-)
74: remote -> cocoon-archetype-block (-)
75: remote -> cocoon-archetype-parent (-)
76: remote -> cocoon-archetype-sample (-)
77: remote -> cocoon-archetype-webapp (-)
78: remote -> cxf-http-basic (-)
79: remote -> cxf-jaxws-javafirst (-)
80: remote -> apacheds-schema-archetype (-)
81: remote -> apacheds-testcase-archetype (-)
82: remote -> maven-ipojo-plugin (Maven Plugin to package iPOJO-powered bundles.)
83: remote -> geronimo-archetype-testsuite (Plugin to help create a testsuite)
84: remote -> geronimo-assembly-archetype (-)
85: remote -> geronimo-plugin-archetype (-)
86: remote -> geronimo-archetype-testsuite (Plugin to help create a testsuite)
87: remote -> geronimo-samples-archetype (Plugin to help create a samples project)
88: remote -> archetypes-command (-)
89: remote -> maven-archetype-archetype (An archetype which contains a sample archetype.)
90: remote -> maven-archetype-j2ee-simple (An archetype which contains a simplifed sample J2EE application.)
91: remote -> maven-archetype-marmalade-mojo (-)
92: remote -> maven-archetype-mojo (An archetype which contains a sample a sample Maven plugin.)
93: remote -> maven-archetype-plugin (An archetype which contains a sample Maven plugin.)
94: remote -> maven-archetype-plugin-site (An archetype which contains a sample Maven plugin site. This archetype can be
 layered upon an
    existing Maven plugin project.)
95: remote -> maven-archetype-portlet (An archetype which contains a sample JSR-268 Portlet.)
96: remote -> maven-archetype-profiles (-)
97: remote -> maven-archetype-quickstart (An archetype which contains a sample Maven project.)
98: remote -> maven-archetype-site (An archetype which contains a sample Maven site which demonstrates some of the suppo
rted document types like
    APT, XDoc, and FML and demonstrates how to i18n your site. This archetype can be layered
    upon an existing Maven project.)
99: remote -> maven-archetype-site-simple (An archetype which contains a sample Maven site.)
100: remote -> maven-archetype-webapp (An archetype which contains a sample Maven Webapp project.)
101: remote -> myfaces-archetype-helloworld (Archetype to create a new webapp based on myfaces)
102: remote -> myfaces-archetype-helloworld-facelets (Archetype to create a new webapp based on MyFaces and Facelets)
103: remote -> myfaces-archetype-helloworld-portlets (Archetype to create a new portlet webapp based on myfaces)
104: remote -> myfaces-archetype-helloworld20 (Archetype to create a new webapp based on MyFaces 2.0)
105: remote -> myfaces-archetype-helloworld20-owb (Archetype to create a new webapp based on MyFaces 2.0 with OpenWebBea
ns)
106: remote -> myfaces-archetype-jsfcomponents (Archetype to create a libary project of JSF components)
107: remote -> myfaces-archetype-trinidad (Archetype to create a new webapp based on Trinidad)
108: remote -> myfaces-archetype-trinidad20 (Archetype to create a new webapp based on Trinidad and JSF 2.0)
109: remote -> myfaces-archetype-trinidad (Archetype to ease the burden of creating a new application based with Trinida
d)
110: remote -> application-archetype (Jetspeed-2 Maven2 Archetype used to generate portal application templates.)
111: remote -> component-archetype (Jetspeed-2 Maven2 Archetype used to generate component templates to
        be used by other components and applications.)
112: remote -> jetspeed-archetype (Jetspeed 2 Maven Archetype)
113: remote -> portal-archetype (Jetspeed-2 Maven2 Archetype used to generate portal instances.)
114: remote -> portal-component-archetype (Jetspeed-2 Maven2 Archetype used to generate component templates to
        be injected/installed as a library in the portal application itself.)
115: remote -> shared-component-archetype (Jetspeed-2 Maven2 Archetype used to generate component templates to
        be installed as a shared library for all portlet/web applications.)
116: remote -> servicemix-bean-service-unit (-)
117: remote -> servicemix-binding-component (-)
118: remote -> servicemix-camel-osgi-bundle (-)
119: remote -> servicemix-camel-service-unit (-)
120: remote -> servicemix-cxf-bc-service-unit (-)
121: remote -> servicemix-cxf-code-first-osgi-bundle (-)
122: remote -> servicemix-cxf-se-service-unit (-)
123: remote -> servicemix-cxf-se-wsdl-first-service-unit (-)
124: remote -> servicemix-cxf-wsdl-first-osgi-bundle (-)
125: remote -> servicemix-drools-service-unit (-)
126: remote -> servicemix-eip-service-unit (-)
127: remote -> servicemix-embedded-simple (-)
128: remote -> servicemix-exec-service-unit (-)
129: remote -> servicemix-file-poller-service-unit (-)
130: remote -> servicemix-file-sender-service-unit (-)
131: remote -> servicemix-file-service-unit (-)
132: remote -> servicemix-ftp-poller-service-unit (-)
133: remote -> servicemix-ftp-sender-service-unit (-)
134: remote -> servicemix-ftp-service-unit (-)
135: remote -> servicemix-http-consumer-service-unit (-)
136: remote -> servicemix-http-provider-service-unit (-)
137: remote -> servicemix-http-service-unit (-)
138: remote -> servicemix-jms-consumer-service-unit (-)
139: remote -> servicemix-jms-provider-service-unit (-)
140: remote -> servicemix-jms-service-unit (-)
141: remote -> servicemix-jsr181-annotated-service-unit (-)
142: remote -> servicemix-jsr181-service-unit (-)
143: remote -> servicemix-jsr181-wsdl-first-service-unit (-)
144: remote -> servicemix-lwcontainer-service-unit (-)
145: remote -> servicemix-mail-service-unit (-)
146: remote -> servicemix-ode-service-unit (-)
147: remote -> servicemix-osgi-bundle (-)
148: remote -> servicemix-osworkflow-service-unit (-)
149: remote -> servicemix-project-root (-)
150: remote -> servicemix-quartz-service-unit (-)
151: remote -> servicemix-saxon-service-unit (-)
152: remote -> servicemix-saxon-xquery-service-unit (-)
153: remote -> servicemix-saxon-xslt-service-unit (-)
154: remote -> servicemix-script-service-unit (-)
155: remote -> servicemix-scripting-service-unit (-)
156: remote -> servicemix-service-assembly (-)
157: remote -> servicemix-service-engine (-)
158: remote -> servicemix-service-unit (-)
159: remote -> servicemix-shared-library (-)
160: remote -> servicemix-smpp-service-unit (-)
161: remote -> servicemix-snmp-service-unit (-)
162: remote -> servicemix-validation-service-unit (-)
163: remote -> servicemix-vfs-service-unit (-)
164: remote -> servicemix-xmpp-service-unit (-)
165: remote -> sling-initial-content-archetype (Maven archetype for initial content)
166: remote -> sling-servlet-archetype (Maven archetype for Sling Servlets)
167: remote -> struts2-archetype-blank (-)
168: remote -> struts2-archetype-convention (-)
169: remote -> struts2-archetype-dbportlet (-)
170: remote -> struts2-archetype-plugin (-)
171: remote -> struts2-archetype-portlet (-)
172: remote -> struts2-archetype-starter (-)
173: remote -> quickstart (Archetype for creating a basic Tapestry 5 application.)
174: remote -> tapestry-archetype (-)
175: remote -> tapestry-simple (Archetype for creating a basic Tapestry 5 application, including Eclipse control files.)

176: remote -> tuscany-binding-archetype (Create a Tuscany binding extension project)
177: remote -> tuscany-contribution-jar (-)
178: remote -> tuscany-contribution-zip (-)
179: remote -> tuscany-quickstart (-)
180: remote -> tuscany-quickstart-bpel (-)
181: remote -> tuscany-quickstart-jsf (-)
182: remote -> tuscany-quickstart-jsonp (-)
183: remote -> tuscany-quickstart-stripes (-)
184: remote -> wicket-archetype-quickstart (-)
185: remote -> appfuse-basic-jsf (Maven 2 archetype that creates a web application with AppFuse embedded in it.)
186: remote -> appfuse-basic-spring (Maven 2 archetype that creates a web application with AppFuse embedded in it.)
187: remote -> appfuse-basic-struts (Maven 2 archetype that creates a web application with AppFuse embedded in it.)
188: remote -> appfuse-basic-tapestry (Maven 2 archetype that creates a web application with AppFuse embedded in it.)
189: remote -> appfuse-core (Maven 2 archetype that creates a backend (Managers, DAOs and Web Services)
        application with AppFuse embedded in it.)
190: remote -> appfuse-modular-jsf (Maven 2 archetype that creates a modular web application with AppFuse. This archetyp
e creates two modules:
        "core" and "web". The core module depends on appfuse-service, while the web module depends on core as well
        as AppFuse's JSF implementation.)
191: remote -> appfuse-modular-spring (Maven 2 archetype that creates a modular web application with AppFuse. This arche
type creates two modules:
        "core" and "web". The core module depends on appfuse-service, while the web module depends on core as well
        as AppFuse's Spring MVC implementation.)
192: remote -> appfuse-modular-struts (Maven 2 archetype that creates a modular web application with AppFuse. This arche
type creates two modules:
        "core" and "web". The core module depends on appfuse-service, while the web module depends on core as well
        as AppFuse's Struts implementation.)
193: remote -> appfuse-modular-tapestry (Maven 2 archetype that creates a modular web application with AppFuse. This arc
hetype creates two modules:
        "core" and "web". The core module depends on appfuse-service, while the web module depends on core as well
        as AppFuse's Tapestry implementation.)
194: remote -> appfuse-basic-jsf (Maven 2 archetype that creates a web application with AppFuse embedded in it.)
195: remote -> appfuse-basic-jsf-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
196: remote -> appfuse-basic-spring (Maven 2 archetype that creates a web application with AppFuse embedded in it.)
197: remote -> appfuse-basic-spring-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
198: remote -> appfuse-basic-struts (Maven 2 archetype that creates a web application with AppFuse embedded in it.)
199: remote -> appfuse-basic-struts-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
200: remote -> appfuse-basic-tapestry (Maven 2 archetype that creates a web application with AppFuse embedded in it.)
201: remote -> appfuse-basic-tapestry-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
202: remote -> appfuse-core (Maven 2 archetype that creates a backend (Managers, DAOs and Web Services)
        application with AppFuse embedded in it.)
203: remote -> appfuse-core-archetype (-)
204: remote -> appfuse-light-jsf-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
205: remote -> appfuse-light-spring-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
206: remote -> appfuse-light-spring-freemarker-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
207: remote -> appfuse-light-spring-security-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
208: remote -> appfuse-light-stripes-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
209: remote -> appfuse-light-struts-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
210: remote -> appfuse-light-tapestry-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
211: remote -> appfuse-light-wicket-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
212: remote -> appfuse-modular-jsf (Maven 2 archetype that creates a modular web application with AppFuse. This archetyp
e creates two modules:
        "core" and "web". The core module depends on appfuse-service, while the web module depends on core as well
        as AppFuse's JSF implementation.)
213: remote -> appfuse-modular-jsf-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
214: remote -> appfuse-modular-spring (Maven 2 archetype that creates a modular web application with AppFuse. This arche
type creates two modules:
        "core" and "web". The core module depends on appfuse-service, while the web module depends on core as well
        as AppFuse's Spring MVC implementation.)
215: remote -> appfuse-modular-spring-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
216: remote -> appfuse-modular-struts (Maven 2 archetype that creates a modular web application with AppFuse. This arche
type creates two modules:
        "core" and "web". The core module depends on appfuse-service, while the web module depends on core as well
        as AppFuse's Struts implementation.)
217: remote -> appfuse-modular-struts-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
218: remote -> appfuse-modular-tapestry (Maven 2 archetype that creates a modular web application with AppFuse. This arc
hetype creates two modules:
        "core" and "web". The core module depends on appfuse-service, while the web module depends on core as well
        as AppFuse's Tapestry implementation.)
219: remote -> appfuse-modular-tapestry-archetype (AppFuse Archetype)
220: remote -> drools4-integration-helper-archetype (Support of the archetype for the Maven plugin)
221: remote -> drools5-integration-helper-archetype (This is an Maven 2 Archetype to support creation of a ready to
                use Maven 2 project with Drools support. This archetype contains
                examples of code based on interface, classes and pre/post
                condition. JUnit 4 examples are also included.)
222: remote -> cargo-archetype-webapp-functional-tests-module (Sample Maven 2 Archetypes showing how to configure Cargo
and Maven to run functional tests
    for a webapp by creating a functional-tests module.)
223: remote -> cargo-archetype-webapp-single-module (Sample Maven 2 Archetypes showing how to configure Cargo and Maven
to run functional tests
    directly from a single webapp module.)
224: remote -> codegen-testcase (-)
225: remote -> cpa-testcase (-)
226: remote -> enunciate-simple-archetype (-)
227: remote -> gmaven-archetype-basic (-)
228: remote -> gmaven-archetype-mojo (-)
229: remote -> gmaven-archetype-basic (-)
230: remote -> gmaven-archetype-mojo (-)
231: remote -> maven-archetype-nbm (Archetype for Netbeans Modules Maven setup)
232: remote -> gwt-maven-plugin (Maven plugin for the Google Web Toolkit.)
233: remote -> latex-maven-archetype (The LaTeX Maven Archetype is kickstarts your LaTeX / Maven projects.)
234: remote -> xmlbeans-maven-plugin (Runs the xmlbeans parser/code generator against schemas in files and dependent jar
s.)
235: remote -> appframework (Archetype for creating application based on JSR 296)
236: remote -> ear-j2ee14 (Archetype for creating J2EE 1.4 EAR)
237: remote -> ear-javaee6 (Archetype for EAR package using Java EE 6)
238: remote -> ear-jee5 (Archetype for creating JEE 5 EAR)
239: remote -> ejb-j2ee13 (An archetype which contains a sample J2EE 1.3 EJB Maven project.)
240: remote -> ejb-j2ee14 (An archetype which contains a sample J2EE 1.4 EJB Maven project.)
241: remote -> ejb-javaee6 (Archetype for an EJB package using Java EE 6.)
242: remote -> ejb-jee5 (JEE 5 ejb jar archetype)
243: remote -> nbm-archetype (Archetype for development of NetBeans modules in Maven.)
244: remote -> nbm-osgi-archetype (Archetype for development of NetBeans modules that can depend on OSGi bundles.)
245: remote -> nbm-suite-root (Root project archetype for creating multi module projects developing NetBeans IDE modules
. Approximately similar in functionality to module suites in NetBeans Ant projects.)
246: remote -> netbeans-platform-app-archetype (Archetype for sample application based on NetBeans Platform. Creates par
ent POM with branding and empty NBM project.)
247: remote -> osgi-archetype (Archetype for development of OSGi bundles using Apache Felix Maven plugin)
248: remote -> pom-root (Root project archetype for creating multi module projects)
249: remote -> webapp-j2ee13 (J2EE 1.3 web application archetype)
250: remote -> webapp-j2ee14 (J2EE 1.4 web application archetype)
251: remote -> webapp-javaee6 (Archetype for a web application using Java EE 6.)
252: remote -> webapp-jee5 (JEE 5 web application archetype)
253: remote -> groovy-maven-archetype (An archetype for creating Maven modules/projects using the Groovy language.)
254: remote -> groovy-mojo-archetype (An archetype for writing Maven 2 plugins in the Groovy language.)
255: remote -> org.openxma.dsl.sample-archetype (-)
256: remote -> sonar-basic-plugin-archetype (Maven archetype to create a basic Sonar plugin)
257: remote -> sonar-gwt-plugin-archetype (Maven archetype to create a Sonar plugin including GWT pages)
258: remote -> cometd-archetype-dojo-jetty6 (-)
259: remote -> cometd-archetype-dojo-jetty7 (-)
260: remote -> cometd-archetype-jquery-jetty6 (-)
261: remote -> cometd-archetype-jquery-jetty7 (-)
262: remote -> coos-plugin-actor (-)
263: remote -> coos-plugin-api (-)
264: remote -> coos-plugin-noapi (-)
265: remote -> jee6-basic-archetype (Basic Java EE application with just configuration for CDI, JSF, JPA and a sample em
pty page.)
266: remote -> jee6-minimal-archetype (Minimal Java EE application with a single page demo of CDI, JSF, JPA and Validati
on to verify everything works.)
267: remote -> jee6-sandbox-archetype (Sandbox project for Java EE 6 with CDI, JSF, JPA and a sample model and test data
 to play around with, try new things, and use as a foundation for tutorials)
268: remote -> jee6-sandbox-demo-archetype (Complete demo example using CDI, JSF, JPA and validation showcasing a number
 of features available in Java EE 6 as well as demonstrating how to make them all work together)
269: remote -> jee6-servlet-basic-archetype (Java EE application for servlet containers (Jetty,Tomcat) with just a singl
e page and a persistence provider .)
270: remote -> jee6-servlet-demo-archetype (Bookmarking application demonstrating JSF, CDI, JPA and Bean Validation on T
omcat/Jetty servlet containers)
271: remote -> jee6-servlet-minimal-archetype (Minimal Java EE application for servlet containers (Jetty,Tomcat) with a
single page demo of CDI, JSF, JPA and Validation to verify everything works.)

and EJB 3.1 (persistence unit not included))
287: remote -> weld-jsf-servlet-minimal (Weld archetype for creating an application using JSF 2.0 and CDI 1.0 for Servle
t Containers (Tomcat 6 / Jetty 6))
288: remote -> jbundle-util-webapp-cgi-archetype (-)
289: remote -> jbundle-util-webapp-files-archetype (-)
290: remote -> jbundle-util-webapp-proxy-archetype (-)
291: remote -> jbundle-util-webapp-redirect-archetype (-)
292: remote -> jbundle-util-webapp-upload-archetype (-)
293: remote -> jbundle-util-webapp-webdav-archetype (-)
294: remote -> jbundle-util-webapp-website-archetype (-)
295: remote -> jbundle-util-webapp-webstart-archetype (-)
296: remote -> jibx-ota-osgi-archetype (-)
297: remote -> jini-service-archetype (Archetype for Jini service project creation)
298: remote -> maven-hpi-plugin (Maven2 plugin for developing Hudson plugins)
299: remote -> makumba-archetype (Archetype for a makumba web-application)
300: remote -> ibean-archetype (An archetype for creating an empty ibean maven project)
301: remote -> ibean-archetype (Creates a new iBean project that talks to an external service i.e. Twitter, Amazon S3, F
lickr). The project will define the dependencies and documented sample
        code for the ibean itself and a a working testcase.)
351: remote -> spring-ws-archetype (Spring Web Services Maven2 Archetype.)
352: remote -> trails-archetype (-)
353: remote -> trails-secure-archetype (-)
354: remote -> tynamo-archetype (-)
355: remote -> wicket-scala-archetype (Basic setup for a project that combines Scala and Wicket,
                depending on the Wicket-Scala project. Includes an example Specs
                test.)
356: remote -> wikbook.archetype (-)
357: remote -> circumflex-archetype (-)
358: remote -> javg-minimal-archetype (-)
Choose a number: 97: Choose version:
```

Comment: had to delete some of the content as it exceed the limit (3000 words)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `choice 15` as a quick start. Just ignore others.

Comment: Right, now it's 97. My mistake.