# Specify archetype for archetype:generate on command line

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-archetype

I'm generating a Maven archetype for a simple project.  I use `archetype:generate`, and it gives me a list of types of archetypes to generate.  I'm pretty sure I want

```
99: remote -> maven-archetype-quickstart (An archetype which contains a sample Maven project.)
```

I can just enter "99" interactively, but I'm trying to write a blog post.  I don't want to tell my readers "search for maven-archetype-quickstart in the hundreds of options", and I know it won't always be number 99.

So, how do I specify on the command line the archetype to generate?

([A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422781/maven-archetypegenerate-excessive-number-of-choice) discusses which archetype to use, but not how to specify it non-interactively)

Comment: Yeah! +1 for this question. That is not documented in the tutorial, and I need a terminal with >9000 rows of backlog in order to search all the alternatives: no pager support!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can provide arguments via system properties, [as in](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html):

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`

Comment: +1. Note: if one wants to generate the *maven-archetype-quickstart* project, then `-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart` can be omitted, because it is the **default** project.