# maven archetype:generate does not find archetype in local catalog

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I have created and installed my own archetype and now I am trying to create a new project with it with the command line. 
When I run

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

I can see that the archetype is installed:

```
19: local -> myOwnArchetype (Archetype - my own archetype)
```

And in the archetype-catalog.xml I find

```
<archetype>
  <groupId>de.rm.trial</groupId>
  <artifactId>myOwnArchetype</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <description>Archetype - my own archetype</description>
</archetype>
```

When I try

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local -DarchetypeGroupId=de.rm.trial -DartifactId=myOwnArchetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 -DgroupId=de.rm.trial.mynew -DartifactId=myNewProject
```

it still asking "Choose number:".

I found this link [Specify archetype for archetype:generate on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909455/specify-archetype-for-archetypegenerate-on-command-line) so I tried it with

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local -DarchetypeGroupId=de.rm.trial -DartifactId=myOwnArchetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 -DgroupId=de.rm.trial.mynew -DartifactId=myNewProject -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Unfortunately maven tells

```
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (de.rm.trial:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
```

I have no more idea, what might be wrong with it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have used `artifactId` instead of `archetypeArtifactId`.  Try the following:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local -DarchetypeGroupId=de.rm.trial -DarchetypeArtifactId=myOwnArchetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 -DgroupId=de.rm.trial.mynew -DartifactId=myNewProject -DinteractiveMode=false
```