# Archetype:generate behavior for maven-archetype-quickstart

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I am trying to create understand why a certain combination of arguments to archetype:generate works where as others don't.  I am attempting this for `maven-archetype-quickstart`.

Project creation works when I specify neither `archetypeVersion` nor `interactiveMode=false`.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId="apache.maven.archetypes" -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DgroupId="com.mycompany.mygroup" -DartifactId=artifact1  -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

This runs in interactive mode of course.  It shows me several versions with the  latest one being 1.1.  This is also confirmed it from [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg:%22org.apache.maven.archetypes%22).  I then tried to get the project creation to work in non-interactive mode.  However, I found that if I specify either `interactiveMode=false` or `archetypeVersion=1.1` or both then the project creation fails; i.e. neither of the following work:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId="apache.maven.archetypes" -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DgroupId="com.mycompany.mygroup" -DartifactId=artifact1  -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeVersion=1.1

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId="apache.maven.archetypes" -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DgroupId="com.mycompany.mygroup" -DartifactId=artifact1  -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DinteractiveMode=false

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId="apache.maven.archetypes" -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DgroupId="com.mycompany.mygroup" -DartifactId=artifact1  -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Finally I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909455/specify-archetype-for-archetypegenerate-on-command-line) and noticed that archetypeGroupID wasn’t specified and decided to try it and it worked, i.e. the following works in non-interactive mode:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DgroupId="com.mycompany.mygroup" -DartifactId=artifact1  -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I am quite confused as to why is that.  I’d appreciate any pointers to help me understand this behavior better.

In each of the problem cases the error (more or less) is as follows:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId="apache.maven.archetypes" -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DgroupId="com.mycompany.mygroup" -DartifactId=artifact1  -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -DinteractiveMode=false
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2).
[WARNING] Use -DarchetypeRepository=<your repository> if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.1/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.633s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Mar 29 22:01:24 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version that you are using -Darchetype is no longer more used.
To create a simple project with Maven using **maven-archetype-quickstart** simple follow the steps:

using the command line type:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=mygroupId -DartifactId=myartifactId
-Dpackage=mypackage -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

of course replacing with your values. Then when you type enter a list of archetypes will be available and then you need type a number of the archetype you want. For the **maven-archetype-quickstart** one (it is the default one) you just need type enter without no number because the maven will assume that you want the default one. After that just confirm the data typing enter and you should see a BUILD SUCCESS.

Comment: Yes, the interactive mode works well.  I was hoping to understand why a particular combination of flags not work in non-interactive mode.